# How to click the radio button using Selenium in Python?

Tags: python, selenium

I am writing a bot programme but i am not able to select the radio button using only this information
[Here is the Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwcjQ.jpg)
I just wanted to click on the radio button not using the class.
Here is my code

```
radio_button = bot.find_element_by_xpath("//label[contains(text(),'I don't have the subject knowledge')]")
radio_button.click()
```

but it gives the following error

> raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
> selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid
> selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression
> //label[contains(text(),'I don't have the subject knowledge')] because
> of the following error: SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on
> 'Document': The string '//label[contains(text(),'I don't have the
> subject knowledge')]' is not a valid XPath expression.   (Session
> info: chrome=90.0.4430.93)

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is some kind of typo with your `xpath` expression.
So please try this.
Hope it will work

```
//label[contains(text(),'have the subject knowledge')]
```

Possibly you will have to click the `input` element inside the `label`.
In this case use this `xpath`:

```
//label[contains(text(),'have the subject knowledge')]/input
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

radioButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//label[contains(text(),'don't have the subject knowledge')]")

radioButton.find_element_by_xpath(".//following-sibling::input").click()

Comment: Please check by yourself what you are trying to answer and only the answer. What is `click`?

Comment: Its not working it's showing the same error as before.

Comment: can you share the url?